Changing Color Of The Dropdownmenu causes the floating label to appear inside
I have a dropdown with a floating label, I want to change the background color of the dropdown but when I do this with the following settings
inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(

filled: true,

fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 171, 0, 0),

),

The floating label appears on the inside and won't move and is fixed on the inside of the dropdown, how do I resolve this?
